# Windows Virtual PC - Discarding Changes On Exit (Win7 Host)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windows-7, development-environment, virtual-machine

I need Virtual PC (VPC) for testing my Visual Studio 2008/2010 applications, and I want to test and debug it using VPC running a clean install of WinXP (nothing else installed).

Back when I was running WinXP, I could launch a VPC session, do whatever I needed to (install my application, run it, debug scenarios, etc.), then exit without saving any of the changes to my virtual machine's hard drive.

There does not seem to be this option under Windows 7 - or, if there is, I have been unsuccessful in activating it.

Is there a way to make sure changes to my virtual machine are not saved?

Regards,
~Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is enabled by using 'undo disk(s)'.  Check out this [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/08/18/windows-virtual-pc-and-undo-disks.aspx) for info.

Comment: Thanks Will! I think this is exactly what I wanted, I just didn't notice it. Doh!

Comment: My pleasure - yeah, I'd had trouble locating this in the past as well!

Comment: Just an FYI: I accepted one of your other answers about Safe Storage Locations - not so much because the DirectorySecurity feature worked for me, but because it could have been caused by another portion of the code writing to the same area.